# CSS width is not working on HTML select tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning Bootstrap v5.0. I am trying to resize the `select` tag with CSS `width` but it is not working. I also tried Bootstrap `.col` and it is also not working.

**My code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Input</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="alert bg-light">
        <div class="container">
            <h4 class="alert-heading">Custom file input</h4>
            <hr>
            <div class="input-group">
                <select class="form-select" style="width: 40px;">
                    <option value="1">C</option>
                    <option value="2">C++</option>
                    <option value="3">Java</option>
                    <option value="4">Python</option>
                    <option value="5">JavaScript</option>
                </select>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" multiple>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I resize this `select` tag?

If it is possible with bootstrap then please suggest me a solution with bootstrap otherwise CSS.

Comment: Your code works in the snippet.

Comment: @PhilipRollins Sir, I am viewing result on Google Chrome Version 90.0.4430.93 (Official Build) (64-bit) . Here it is not working

Comment: Try using `max-width` instead of `width`, should over ride any bootstrap values.

Comment: Thank you so much sir @PhilipRollins . After adding "max-width" now it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `width` with `max-width`, and your select tag will behave as expected.

Bootstrap actually adds a style rule which makes the width of the `select` very fluid.

```
select {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
}
```

`width` cannot override these style rules, which is why you should be using `max-width`

Comment: Thank you so much sir.
After adding "max-width" now it is working as expected.